# Is it possible to have consumer running without producer attached?

Tags: v4l2loopback

I'm playing around with v4l2loopback and I'm trying to have a gstreamer consumer run with the default timeout image when there is no producer but it's failing.

How the v4l2loopback device is setup:

```
sudo utils/v4l2loopback-ctl set-fps /dev/video20 20
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video20 -c timeout=50
sudo utils/v4l2loopback-ctl set-caps /dev/video20 "UYVY:640x480@20/1"
sudo utils/v4l2loopback-ctl set-timeout-image /dev/video20 <path_to_black_image>
```

The command for producer and consumer:

```
#Producer
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=UYVY,framerate=20/1 ! timeoverlay ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video20

#Consumer
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video20 ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=xvimagesink
```

It works flawlessly when a producer is attached to the loopback device first, then a consumer after. In this scenario, when the producer is removed, the consumer would playback the timeout image with the configured FPS.

However, if trying to run the consumer without a producer, it errors out as below.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2src.c(658): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Buffer pool activation failed
Execution ended after 0:00:00.006248059
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Any idea how to overcome this issue?